# Outlook VBA - how to copy the currently selected text into clipboard?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, vba, clipboard

### My question

How can get the **currently selected text** in Microsoft Outlook 2007

- in an open message window
- or in the currently selected message in the preview pane

and **copy** it into the clipboard?

I am using Microsoft Outlook 2007.

---

### What I already tried

I know that I can use DataObjects to put text into the clipboard or get text from the clipboard.

The difficulty is to **get the currently selected text**

I tried the following commands:

- Outlook.copy
- Outlook.selection.copy
- Outlook.activeexplorer.selection.item(1). ...
  in many variations, but with no success.

I found some sources stating that it would not be possible to get the currently selected text in Outlook via VBA but I think it must at least be possible to invoke a Ctrl-C (copy) command and then use the content of the clipboard.

I also stumbled upon some solutions with the Inspector as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/791242/92184), but I got an error message.
Maybe it is because I forgot to reference the "MS Word Object Library" - I'll try that on Monday.

Comment: What have you tried already? What were the results? Where are you getting stuck exactly?

Comment: Thank you for your comment - sorry! I was really under pressure and in a hurry, but that's not the right and polite way to ask a question here. I've edited my question and would be thankful for removing the downvote. Thanks as well for your detailed reply - I'll try that out on Monday, when I have access to the computer again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Outlook uses Word (if installed) as its editor, it's a bit of a pain to get to get it. :)

You have to reference the Word application, then the Word document, then the selection.

For the following code to work in Outlook you need to add a Reference (*VBA Editor -> Tools -> References*) to the "Microsoft Word  Object Library", and one to the "Microsoft Forms  Object Library", so that we can actually copy the text the system clipboard.

*Note:* For me, in Office 2013, the MS Forms object wasn't in the list, so I just added a UserForm to the VBA project, which added the reference automatically, and then just deleted the form.  The reference stuck.

Anyhow I dug around many sources and here's some code I stuck together that will copy the highlighted text to the clipboard, with some basic error checking (tested in Outlook 2013):

```
Public Sub CopyTextToClipBoard()

    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objInsp As Outlook.Inspector

    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim objSel As Word.Selection
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Reference the current Outlook item
    Set objItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
        If objItem.Class = olMail Then
            Set objInsp = objItem.GetInspector
            If objInsp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
                Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
                Set objWord = objDoc.Application
                Set objSel = objWord.Selection

                On Error GoTo NotText
                With New MSForms.DataObject
                    .SetText objSel.Text
                    .PutInClipboard
                End With
                On Error Resume Next       

            End If
        End If
    End If

    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing
    Set objSel = Nothing
    Set objInsp = Nothing

NotText:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Data on clipboard is not text."
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, it works fine - even if the text is selected in the preview pane (`Outlook 2007`)! (Sorry for my late feedback)